# Are iOS 5 Apps Supported on Facebook App Store?

Tags: facebook, ios5, submission

Please can can anyone help me find out if the Facebook App Store supports iOS 5 Apps?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For an application to be eligible for the Facebook App Center, it has to be ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/guidelines/)):

- An app on Facebook.com in a canvas page
- A mobile app built for iOS or Android that uses Single Sign-On for iOS or Single Sign-On for Android
- A mobile web app that uses Facebook Login and has an immediately logged-in, personalized experience
- A website that uses Facebook Login and has an immediately logged-in, personalized
  experience

In this instance, Facebook Single Sign On doesn't mean the Facebook integration within iOS 6 ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/), [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/)), and as such iOS 5 Apps are eligible **if they use Single Sign On**.

Comment: @user1809427 No problem, could you please accept my answer if it's suitable for you? Just select the tick on the left hand side.